# Como diferenciar um post novo de um post fixo no wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Eu preciso saber se um post é um post novo ou é apenas um post fixo.

Meu codigo é esse aki:

```
<div class="row padding " >
   <div class="col-md-5 padding ">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <?php
            if ( is_sticky ()) echo '<div class="ribbon ribbon-top-left"> 
            <span>fixo</span></div>'    ?>
        <?php
        if ( is_page() !=1 ) If($cont == 0) echo '<div class="ribbon ribbon-top-left"> 
        <span>novo</span></div>'    ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 padding ">
         <!-- Título do post -->
         <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>


        <!-- Autor -->
        <h5><?php the_author(); ?>,

        <!-- Data -->
        <?php  echo  get_the_date(); ?>

        <p>Última atualização: <?php the_modified_time(); ?></p>
        </h5>

        <!-- Resumo do post -->
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Eu gostaria de por a `div` escrito novo no post mais recente mas da maneira que eu fiz se a pessoa fixar um post a `div` acaba indo para o post errado, segue uma imagem marcando onde deveria estar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acredito que o Wordpress não tenha uma function default para isso, deverás ter de criar uma de acordo com o que considerares que um novo post é novo (menos de 1 hora ou menos de 24 horas, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como não obtive uma resposta e não conseguir achar uma função decidir seguir a dica do [iamdlm](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/95452/iamdlm)

```
<?php $hora =  current_time ('timestamp') - get_the_time('U') ;
if ( $hora <= 259200 ) echo '<div class="ribbon ribbon-top-left"><span>novo</span></div>';    ?>
```

Como funciona?
Bem o current_time ('timestamp') busca a hora atual em [unix](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Era_Unix) e o get_the_time('U') busca a hora e a data de quando o post foi publicado em [unix](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Era_Unix), Ok e agora? Subtraia os valores e adicione a uma variável apos isso é só fazer um If para ver se o valor é maior ou menor que o valor em segundos que você colocou que no meu caso é 72h e pronto ta feito

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]